# Given the vertices of a solid face, compute the distance of a point from the face

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I am writing a program where I need to compute the ordinary distance of a point from a face of a solid (imagine, for instance, a point inside a cube).

I have all the vertices of the face *(x,y,z)* [or *(x,y,z,w)* in homogeneous coordinates]. I was wondering if there is some computationally comfortable/efficient way to compute the euclidean distance of a given point from the face.

I am aware of the formula of "distance from a point to a plane", but I would like something more straightforward, possibly not based on the plane coefficients, which can provide the distance only using the coordinates of the point and of 3 of the face vertices. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using three vertices of the face, compute the unit normal vector to the face.  This can be computed as follows:  If $A, B, C$ are three vertices then

$n = \dfrac{ v }{|v|} $

where $v = (B - A) \times (C - A) $

The distance between a point $P$ and the face is simply $ | (P - A) \cdot n | $. (That is, the absolute value of the dot product of the vector $(P - A)$ with the normal vector $n$).

Comment: but then you do not know if the vertical  from the point hit the triangle ABC

Comment: The point on the plane of the face that has the shortest distance to point $P$ doesn't have to be in triangle $ABC$, or even at any point in the face.

Comment: If $d = (P - A) \cdot n $ then the foot of the perpendicular is $F = P - d n $

Comment: you are right, if  "distance from the face" means "distance from (the plane of ) the face"

Comment: @Potato This answer is much better than I was expecting. If this work fine it's going to be great and really efficient. I already have those normals too, because needed to determine if a face is visible.  Thanks a lot!  I am going to try it :-)

Comment: @PotatoFor now I will accept this answer and I will get back in case I see some issue in practical implementation :-)

Comment: @G Cab Thank you. Yes in my case the point is "inside" the cube, so the distance would be from the point to the plane on which the face is.